# for loop but start at middle Python

Tags: python, list, loops

Does anyone know is it possible to start at the element `['d']` instead of `['a']` with this code?
I thought may be putting `y+3` but that doesn't seem to work.

```
list_ = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]
for y in list_:
    print(y)
```

This code prints:

```
['a']
['b']
['c']
['d']
['e']
['f']
['g']
['h']
```

But I want it to print:

```
['d']
['e']
['f']
['g']
['h']
```

Comment: Check out list slicing in the documentation: `list[3:]` (also don't use the name 'list' as a variable).

Comment: You can create a slice of the list or use indexing

Comment: Please expand the question to explain *why* you want to start in the middle.  There may be a more direct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) :

```
from itertools import islice

list_ = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]

for y in islice(list_, list_.index(['d']), None):
    print(y)
```

with a flag:

```
start = False

list_ = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]

for y in list_:
    if y == ['d']:
        start = True
    if start:
        print(y)
```

or simply using slicing:

```
list_ = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]

for y in list_[list_.index(['d']):]:
    print(y)
```

Also try to rename your variable because `list` is the Python `list` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]
for y in range(3,len(list)):
    print(list[y])
```

this will output what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can "slice" the list within the loop as follows:

```py
list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]
for y in list[3:]:
    print(y)
```

or, you can use range where the first parameter is the starting point.

```py
for y in range(3, len(list)):
    print(list[y])
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to slice the list before you iterate over it:

```
for y in list[3:]:
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are trying to start at the middle, but no matter how many itens there are you can do this:

```
list_ = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]

for y in list_[int(len(list_)/2):]:
    print(y)
```

it will check the number of itens and divide it by 2 and cast it as an integer value. The loop will begin from there.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.dropwhile` provides this functionality.

```
from itertools import dropwhile


for x in dropwhile(lambda x: x != ['d'], list):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `start` and `stop` built into `range`:

```
list_ = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h']]
for y in range(3, len(list_)):
    print(list_[y])
```

Output:

```
['d']
['e']
['f']
['g']
['h']
```